# how to use validation to stop inserting the data in database in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

I am beginner in angular and i built a simple reactive form in which I added validation. When I leave input fields empty and then click on submit button, the validation works but also the empty data of the field inserted in the database which i does not want to happen. So please help me with this.
Below this line is my code.

gender.add.component.ts

`

```
    genderData: FormGroup;
      gender: any = [];
      validate: boolean = false;
      @Output() submitted = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
      @Input() get data(): any {
        return this._data;
      }
      set data(data: any) {
        this._data = data || null;
      }
      private _data: gender;
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private genderService: GenderService) {
        this.genderData = this.fb.group({
          id: [''],
          genderid: ['', Validators.required],
          priority: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(255)]],
          createby: ['', Validators.required],
        });
       }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.genderService.getAssociativeData().subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.gender = response;
        });
      }
    
      onSubmit() {
          this.validate = true;
          const data = this.genderData.value;
            data.createby =
            '0x0E1DA7C4F8F9FAE2C9A4A59528FF91DC400CB152B497C05E8491610E42092C9F';
          this.genderService.addNewGender(data).subscribe((response) => {
            this.submitted.emit(true);
          });
        }
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const formData = changes['data'].currentValue;

    this.genderData.setValue({
      id: formData.ID,
      genderid: formData.Gender,
      priority: formData.Priority,
      createby: formData.CreateBy,
    });
  }

  get f():{[key: string]: AbstractControl}{
    return this.genderData.controls;
  }
```

`

gender.add.component.html

```
`<form class="new-added-form" [formGroup]="genderData">
  <input type="hidden" formControlName="id" value="">
  <input type="hidden" formControlName="createby" value="0x0E1DA7C4F8F9FAE2C9A4A59528FF91DC400CB152B497C05E8491610E42092C9F">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="lblgenderID" class="form-label">Subject:</label>
            <select formControlName="genderid" class="form-control" id="gender" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':validate && f['genderid'].errors}">
              <option disabled>Select Subject</option>
              <option *ngFor="let list of gender" value="{{list.GenderID}}">{{list.GenderName}}</option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="validate && f['genderid'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f['genderid'].errors['required']">Subject is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="lblPriority" class="form-label">Priority:</label>
          <input type="number" formControlName="priority" class="form-control" id="chapter_priority" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': validate && f['priority'].errors}">
          <div *ngIf="validate && f['priority'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f['priority'].errors['required']">Priority is required</div>
            <div *ngIf="f['priority'].errors['maxlength']">Priority should be 255 long</div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit($event)">Submit</button>
       </div>
  </div>
</form>
`
```

gender.list.component.html

```
`<div class="card height-auto">
  <div class="card-body">
      <div class="heading-layout1">
          <div class="item-title">
              <h3>{{tableHeading}}</h3>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Add New</button>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table id="genderTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm row-border hover display data-table" *ngIf="!!gender && gender.length">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Gender</th>
                      <th>Priority</th>
                      <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let item of gender">
                      <td>{{item.GenderName}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.Priority}}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                          <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" (click)="edit(item.GenderID)"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Edit</a>&nbsp;
                          <a *ngIf="item.CStatus != 'Delete'" (click)="delete(item.GenderID)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>&nbsp;
                          <a *ngIf="item.CStatus == 'Delete' || item.CStatus == 'Deactive'" (click)="activate(item.GenderID)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-up"></i> Active</a>&nbsp;
                          <a *ngIf="item.CStatus == 'Delete' || item.CStatus == 'Active'" (click)="deactivate(item.GenderID)" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"><i class="fa-solid fa-down"></i> Deactive</a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Gender</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <app-gender-add (submitted)="onSubmitted($event)" [data]="editData"></app-gender-add>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`
```

gender.list.component.ts

```
`constructor(private genderService: GenderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getGender();
  }

  onSubmitted(isSubmitted: boolean) {
    if (isSubmitted) {
      this.genderService.getAllGender().subscribe((response) => {
        this.gender = response;
        $('#genderTable').DataTable().length = this.gender.length;
        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
      });
    }
  }

  getGender() {
    this.genderService.getAllGender().subscribe((response) => {
      this.gender = response;
    });
  }

  activate(genderId: string) {
    this.genderService.activate({ id: genderId }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.getGender();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  deactivate(genderId: string) {
    let deactivated = this.genderService
      .deactivate({ id: genderId })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.getGender();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  delete(genderId: string) {
    let deactivated = this.genderService.delete({ id: genderId }).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.getGender();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  edit(genderId: string) {
    this.genderService.getData(genderId).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.editData = response;

        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

`
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. But in your onSubmit, just check if the form is valid before you continue? Something like if(this.genderData.invalid) return;

Comment: @MikeOne i tried your approach but when i fill all my fields and then click on submit button then it goes inside the if(this.genderData.invalid) condition.

Comment: @MikeOne whenever i leave the input field empty and click on submit button that time the validation working well but the empty data of empty fields also inserted in the database and i don't want this

Answer (score -2):

In addition to validation on the Angular side, you can provide required HTML input validation via the `required` attribute. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required).
Just to exemplify the answer:

```
<input 
    type="number" 
    class="myclass"
    formControlName="priority" 
    required
>
```